# put application in startup

Tags: windows, startup

I am planning to start my application whenever the user starts the computer. ASFA I know, there are two options available to me:

- put the application link to startup folder
- Keep a the startup-registry location updated with application path

However, the problem is, AVs like Kasperesky reports the registry paths (if added by an app) as keyloggers. Just wanted to hear from you people, which is better? Adding a shortcut to startup folder or using the registry way.

Comment: It sounds like adding via registry isn't an option for you. What causes it to be reported as a key-logger?

Comment: If you want a process to start when the computer starts then you probably want a service. You probably mean that you want it to start when the user logs on. Is that so? The `Run`key in the registry should be fine. Perhaps you are doing it wrong? Are you setting the key from your install program which runs elevated?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan: I agree. Your choice would be best for an app without a UI.

Comment: @Stealth Rabbi: it is reporting my application as a suspicious program since it has added run registry keys.

Comment: @David I am setting up the regkey from my application itself.

Comment: Do it from your installer. That should sort it out.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I really would prefer that you didn't force my app to start whenever I reboot. So, if you really insist, then please put it in the **Startup folder** and don't hide it in the Windows registry where I will never be able to find it. There may be times when I need this thing not to start up every time, so please let me do the choosing by putting the shortcut where I can see it and manage it. Otherwise, if it gives me too much trouble, I may just start up Control Panel > Add or Remove Programs, and you really don't want that, do you?